# Intellij "Jar with dependencies" artifact results in misaligned JavaFX checkboxes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

*Left side of picture:* It is when it is run  directly from intellij

*Right side of picture:* Created fat jar (which is created by the feature called *"Jar with dependencies"*) is run as double click from mouse
[image: The difference between gui side of same application]

As you can see, Checkboxes are not aligned .**Every component is created by code not from fxml**...What can be the cause of this?

**Edit:**

*First of all, width and height are fixed. Thus they will never change. I disabled Them* Below you can find the code.

```
HBox row1 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label nameLbl = new Label("Login Email");
        nameLbl.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        nameLbl.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        txtEmail = new TextField();
        txtEmail.setPrefSize(DefaultValues.TEXTAREA_WIDTH,20);
        txtEmail.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(!newValue)
                checkLicence();
        });
        row1.getChildren().addAll(nameLbl,txtEmail);

        HBox row2 = new HBox(10);
        Label passwordLbl = new Label("Password");
        passwordLbl.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        passwordLbl.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        txtPassword = new PasswordField();
        txtPassword.setPrefSize(DefaultValues.TEXTAREA_WIDTH,20);
        row2.getChildren().add(passwordLbl);
        row2.getChildren().add(txtPassword);

        HBox row3 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label refreshTime = new Label("Refresh Time");
        refreshTime.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        refreshTime.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        txtRefreshTime = new TextField();
        txtRefreshTime.setPrefSize(DefaultValues.TEXTAREA_WIDTH,20);
        txtRefreshTime.setPromptText("Seconds");
        txtRefreshTime.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
                txtRefreshTime.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
            }
        });
        row3.getChildren().add(refreshTime);
        row3.getChildren().add(txtRefreshTime);

        HBox row3_1 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label userCountLbl = new Label("User Count(for point calc.)");
        userCountLbl.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        userCountLbl.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        txtUserCountForPointCalc = new TextField();
        txtUserCountForPointCalc.setPrefSize(DefaultValues.TEXTAREA_WIDTH,20);
        txtUserCountForPointCalc.setPromptText("Not very important");
        txtUserCountForPointCalc.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
                txtUserCountForPointCalc.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
            }
        });
        row3_1.getChildren().add(userCountLbl);
        row3_1.getChildren().add(txtUserCountForPointCalc);

        HBox row4 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label showNotifications = new Label("Show Notifications");
        showNotifications.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH - 10);
        showNotifications.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        cbShowNotifications = new CheckBox();
        cbShowNotifications.setPrefWidth(180);
        Button btnClearNotificationCache = new Button("Clear Notification Cache");
        btnClearNotificationCache.setOnAction(e -> {
            notifiedAssignedToMeTickets.clear();
            notifiedUnassignedTickets.clear();
        });
        row4.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        row4.getChildren().addAll(showNotifications,cbShowNotifications,btnClearNotificationCache);

        HBox row5 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label autoReplyCompanies = new Label("Auto-Reply Companies");
        autoReplyCompanies.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        autoReplyCompanies.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        txtAutoReplyCompanies = new TextField();
        txtAutoReplyCompanies.setPrefSize(DefaultValues.TEXTAREA_WIDTH,20);
        txtAutoReplyCompanies.setPromptText("(For Unassigned Tickets..)Seperate with ';' for multiple companies");
        row5.getChildren().add(autoReplyCompanies);
        row5.getChildren().add(txtAutoReplyCompanies);

        //txtAutoReplyModules
        HBox row5_2 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label autoReplyModules = new Label("Auto-Reply Modules");
        autoReplyModules.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        autoReplyModules.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        txtAutoReplyModules = new TextField();
        txtAutoReplyModules.setPrefSize(DefaultValues.TEXTAREA_WIDTH,20);
        txtAutoReplyModules.setPromptText("(For Unassigned Tickets..)Seperate with ';' for multiple modules");
        row5_2.getChildren().add(autoReplyModules);
        row5_2.getChildren().add(txtAutoReplyModules);

        HBox row6 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label autoReplyMessage = new Label("Auto-Reply Message");
        autoReplyMessage.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        autoReplyMessage.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        txtAutoReplyMessage = new TextArea();
        txtAutoReplyMessage.setPrefSize(DefaultValues.TEXTAREA_WIDTH,65);
        row6.getChildren().add(autoReplyMessage);
        row6.getChildren().add(txtAutoReplyMessage);

        //cbStatistics
        HBox row6_1 = new HBox(10);
        Label searchStatistics = new Label("Process Statistics");
        searchStatistics.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH - 10);
        searchStatistics.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        cbStatistics = new CheckBox();
        cbStatistics.setSelected(true);
        cbStatistics.setPrefWidth(180);
        row6_1.getChildren().addAll(searchStatistics,cbStatistics);

        HBox row7 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label searchUnassignedsLbl = new Label("Search Unassigned Tickets");
        searchUnassignedsLbl.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH - 10);
        searchUnassignedsLbl.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        cbSearchUnassigneds = new CheckBox();
        cbSearchUnassigneds.setSelected(true);
        cbSearchUnassigneds.setPrefWidth(180);
        //row7.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        row7.getChildren().addAll(searchUnassignedsLbl,cbSearchUnassigneds);

        HBox row8 = new HBox(10);
        //row1.setPadding();
        Label searchAssignedToMe = new Label("Search Replied to u");
        searchAssignedToMe.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        searchAssignedToMe.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        cbSearchAssignedToMeTickets = new CheckBox();
        cbSearchAssignedToMeTickets.setSelected(true);
        cbSearchAssignedToMeTickets.setPrefSize(DefaultValues.TEXTAREA_WIDTH,20);
        row8.getChildren().add(searchAssignedToMe);
        row8.getChildren().add(cbSearchAssignedToMeTickets);

        HBox row9 = new HBox(10);
        Label checkUpdateLbl = new Label("Check Updates");
        checkUpdateLbl.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH - 10);
        checkUpdateLbl.setPadding(new Insets(4,0,0,0));
        cbCheckUpdates = new CheckBox();
        cbCheckUpdates.setSelected(checkUpdatesSetting);
        cbCheckUpdates.setPrefWidth(180);
        Button btnUpdateUpdater = new Button("Update Updater");
        btnUpdateUpdater.setOnAction(event -> downloadUpdaterUpdate());
        //btnUpdateUpdater.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        row9.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        row9.getChildren().addAll(checkUpdateLbl,cbCheckUpdates,btnUpdateUpdater);

        HBox row10 = new HBox();
        Label dummy = new Label("");
        dummy.setPrefWidth(DefaultValues.LABEL_WIDTH);
        Button btnSaveSettings = new Button("Save Settings");
        btnSaveSettings.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(txtEmail.getLength() == 0 || txtPassword.getLength() == 0 || txtRefreshTime.getLength() == 0)
                showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"","ilk 3 alan boş olamaz");
            else{

                Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call(){

                    shutDownCalled = true;
                    waitExecutorShutDown();

                    checkLicence();
                    Settings st = new Settings();
                    st.setEmail(txtEmail.getText().trim());
                    st.setPassword(txtPassword.getText().trim());
                    st.setRefreshTime(Integer.parseInt(txtRefreshTime.getText().trim()));
                    st.setUserCountForPointCalculation(txtUserCountForPointCalc.getLength() == 0 ? DefaultValues.userCountForPointCalculation : Integer.parseInt(txtUserCountForPointCalc.getText()));
                    st.setShowNotifications(cbShowNotifications.isSelected());
                    st.setAutoReplyCompanies(txtAutoReplyCompanies.getText().trim());
                    st.setAutoReplyModules(txtAutoReplyModules.getText().trim());
                    st.setAutoReplyMessage(txtAutoReplyMessage.getText().trim());
                    st.setSearchUnassignedTickets(cbSearchUnassigneds.isSelected());
                    st.setSearchAssignedToMeTickets(cbSearchAssignedToMeTickets.isSelected());
                    st.setCheckUpdates(cbCheckUpdates.isSelected());
                    st.setProcessStatistics(cbStatistics.isSelected());

                    Settings.saveNormalBotSettingsToFile(st);
                    settings = st;
                    needLogin = true;
                    initData(false);
                    return null;
                    }
                };
                new Thread(task).start();
                mainTabs.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            }
        });
        row10.getChildren().addAll(dummy,btnSaveSettings);


        VBox vb = new VBox(9);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,0,10));
        vb.getChildren().addAll(row1,row2,row3,row3_1,row5,row5_2,row6,row6_1,row4,row7,row8,row9,row10);

        return vb;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please elaborate.

Comment: It is very obvious. Checkboxes are not aligned ....

Comment: One does not simply check other's checkbox alignment on stackoverflow.

Comment: Title says it all. It is  either javafx or intellij bug. Thus stackoverflow issue.

Comment: I must say that the title does not indicate anything at all. But, back to the issue at hand, insert logging and check for margins, etc.

Comment: @Trinopoty but why would i check for margins? They are same for every side of picture?. Why do you mean by logging?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168744/discussion-between-trinopoty-and-mert-serimer).

Comment: @James_D so what can be the cause of it? Why are they different? ISNT IT SAME CODE WHEN IT IS CREATED AS FAT JAR OR RUN FROM IDEA?

Comment: Sure. But we have no idea how you're managing your layout. What guarantees have you made that it will be laid out correctly in the first place? How do you know you will get the same result if, e.g. you run under a different Jdk version? (Also, there is no need to shout.)

Comment: try a clean build maybe? sometimes old stuff remains that causes problems.

Comment: @James_D can you check the creation of code of tab.

Comment: Post is edited^^

Answer (score 1):

An `HBox` makes no guarantee about the amount of space it actually assigns to any child node that is contained inside it. It merely guarantees to place them in order, with a minimum gap if you specify a spacing, and makes a best effort to size each child node to its preferred size. Many factors which are beyond your control will affect the actual size of each node, including font sizes (which depend on the available fonts), total size available to the `HBox`, etc etc. All these may change depending on the platform the application is running on, including depending on the JDK version.

So trying to line things up vertically by placing them in a collection of `HBox`s and setting the preferred sizes of the child nodes is simply not a reliable way to approach this (and is not designed as such). The problem is there is no real way to connect the layout of one `HBox` to the layout of another `HBox`: they are all laid out independently. If you want to lay components out so they are aligned relative to each other both horizontally and vertically, you should use a `GridPane`, which is specifically designed for that purpose.

It is generally a very bad idea (not just in JavaFX; this applies to most UI toolkits) to hard-code sizes of anything, so anytime you are using this as a solution, there is almost certainly a better approach.

The basic idea behind using a `GridPane` would look like:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
// padding around entire grid:
grid.setPadding(new Insets(4);
grid.setHgap(10);
grid.setVgap(9);

Label nameLbl = new Label("Login Email");
// column 0, row 0:
grid.add(nameLbl, 0, 0);

txtEmail = new TextField();
txtEmail.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if(!newValue)
        checkLicence();
});
// column 1, row 0, span 2 columns:
grid.add(txtEmail, 1, 0, 2, 1);

// ...

Label searchAssignedToMe = new Label("Search Replied to u");
// column 0, row 7:
grid.add(searchAssignedToMe, 0, 7);

cbSearchAssignedToMeTickets = new CheckBox();
cbSearchAssignedToMeTickets.setSelected(true);
// column 1, row 7, span two columns:
grid.add(cbSearchAssignedToMeTickets, 1, 7, 2, 1);

Label checkUpdateLbl = new Label("Check Updates");
// column 0, row 8:
grid.add(checkUpdateLbl, 0, 8);

cbCheckUpdates = new CheckBox();
cbCheckUpdates.setSelected(checkUpdatesSetting);
// column 1, row 8:
grid.add(cbCheckUpdates, 1, 8);

Button btnUpdateUpdater = new Button("Update Updater");
btnUpdateUpdater.setOnAction(event -> downloadUpdaterUpdate());
// column 2, row 8:
grid.add(btnUpdateUpdater, 2, 8);

// ...

Button btnSaveSettings = new Button("Save Settings");
btnSaveSettings.setOnAction(...);
// center button horizontally in its cells (it spans the whole row):
GridPane.setHalignment(btnSaveSettings, HPos.CENTER);
// column 0, row 9, span 3 columns:
grid.add(btnSaveSettings, 0, 9, 3, 1);
```

You can completely configure how any potential extra space is allocated among the columns (using `ColumnConstraints` instances), among the rows (using `RowConstraints` instances), and how the controls are aligned within their individual cell(s). You can also specify these on a node-by-node basis if you need.

You probably want, for example, `hgrow` of the three columns to be `SOMETIMES`, `SOMETIMES`, and `ALWAYS`; you may need to set the `fillWidth` of the `TextInputControl`s to `true`.

See the [`GridPane` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html), which explains this all completely.

Comment: Unbelievable answer. Thanks for so much effort.  Very good info.